# Energy in Destructive interference of waves

Tags: energy, waves, energy-conservation, interference

Let's consider two waves on a string, having equal frequency, wavelength and amplitude. The phase difference between the two travelling waves is π. As a result, they interfere destructively, and the resultant amplitude is zero. The question is, where does the energy of the waves go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on how the waves are created on the string and applying the energy conservation conditions. In the [example here](https://cnx.org/contents/pZH6GMP0@1.265:atV-gRHg@3/Interference-of-Waves)  the 180 degree phase difference is introduced on the string by a reflection on the wall, and it is the wall that takes up the energy.

If there are two sources from the two ends of the string I expect heat would take up the balance of energy, i.e. the atoms and molecules of the string vibrating strongly and radiating, but I guess also the two sources could react mechanically taking up energy.

(In complicated l[aser interference experiments](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-006-video-demonstrations-in-lasers-and-optics-spring-2008/demonstrations-in-physical-optics/destructive-interference-2014-where-does-the-light-go/) itis seen that the energy is returned to the source.)